# Virtual host subdomain on Bitnami points to the same page

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

**I want to create two subdomains pointing to different folders** in a Apache server (running the Bitnami Wamp Stack) so that entering "codeigniter.example.com" shows the content at "\frameworks\codeigniter\htdocs" and "codeignitertwo.example.com" shows "\frameworks\codeignitertwo\htdocs".

My configurations are the following, the "bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf" includes both framework's virtual hosts:

```
Include "/frameworks/codeigniter/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
Include "/frameworks/codeignitertwo/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
```

The httpd-vhosts.conf file from the first domain contains:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName codeigniter.example.com
  ServerAlias codeigniter.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs"
  <Directory "/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs">
    Options +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None

    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

While the httpd-vhosts.conf file from the second domain contains (it is almost the same):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName codeignitertwo.example.com
  ServerAlias codeignitertwo.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/frameworks/codeignitertwo/htdocs"
  <Directory "/frameworks/codeignitertwo/htdocs">
    Options +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None

    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

  </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

Both subdomain names are correctly created on the hosts file like this (I'm testing on localhost):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       codeigniter.example.com
127.0.0.1       codeignitertwo.example.com
```

When I access "codeigniter.example.com" the correct page loads **however when accessing "codeignitertwo.example.com" the first subdomain loads, like if it the DocumentRoot was  "/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs". Why this happens? What I'm doing wrong?**

Update: I restart the Apache service after each change.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the entry for codeignitertwo.example.com in the hosts file?

Comment: @draxxxeus sorry I wrote the incorrect line on the question! The line "127.0.0.1       codeignitertwo.example.com" does exists on the hosts file. Question updated.

Comment: Perhaps try flushing your dns cache on this machine? I had this issue on my mac once and a dns flush fixed the problem.

Comment: @SlyRaskal sadly I flushed the dns cache with "ipconfig /flushdns" with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `NameVirtualHost *:80` line from both of your framework's vhost config files and instead add it to the top of the 'bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf'.  This way you only make that call once, rather than twice since it's redundant anyway.

Comment: Nope, no luck removing the duplicated NameVirtualHost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it!

Word of advice to anyone trying to create a virtual host **while using a Framework** (like Codeigniter and probably CakePHP), if you are completely sure you did a correct virtual host configuration, then you are probably facing incorrect path variables inside the framework.

The way to solve is actually very simple, look at the "index.php" from your htdocs and fix the following variables:

$system_path, $application_folder

Also you might need some changes in the configuration folder of your framework.

Comment: Hi Alejandro I have the same exact problem with Codeigniter. I tried all sorts of fixes but for some reason internal pages doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @sunskin, given that "internal pages doesn't work", it sounds to me like an incorrect $application_folder path on your index.php, verify again this path. The thing is that if you can see HTML content on your subdomain, then it means that the virtual host is very likely correctly configured, all other issues are on the side of the Codeigniter configuration, paths, or even the PHP page content.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply! I could fix it. I missed rewrite part on my virtualhost entry. That fixed it